# Auto Restart of Tomcat server in JAVA EE under IntelJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a project built upon JAVA EE, I'm using **tomcat** and for the ide I'm working on **Intellij**.
While developping,I have to stop and restart my tomcat server each time I add new line of code or edit on it, which is just so much waste of time.
So, I was wondring if there is a way to make **an auto-restart of the server on new saved  code**.
Like some sort of  **--watch script**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around on the tomcat configurations and got it to work.
there are the configuration that worked for me:

[image: tomcat-configs]

PS:to show this tab click on tomcat in the top right -> edit configurations.